# My app throws exception when manually terminating it from background

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, exception, testing

Hello i have my iPhone 5s connected to my mac at the moment, because i am testing my almost done app on my real phone.

When i launch it from Xcode it automatically launches on my phone, but the problem is when i am in the app on my phone, and i hit the Home button, so it goes to the background and from there if i hit home button twice and kill my app, in Xcode an exception is thrown in the main() function. There is no error description in the console.

Is this normal or can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is running is background mode and you are trying to kill it using device home button. that time app is running with Xcode so when you kill it that time Xcode is disconnect with running app.

**so don't worry it is not an error so no need to do anything for that.**

I hope you will understand what I explain here.

I hope it will help you!